# Android ViewModelProviderFactory in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-architecture-components

I'm experimenting with the [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) from Google. Specifically I want to implement a [ViewModelProvider.Factory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.Factory.html) to create a ViewModel that takes constructor parameters, like so:

```
class MyFactory(val handler: Handler) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>?): T {
        return MyViewModel(handler) as T
    }
}
```

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
class MyViewModel(val handler: Handler) : ViewModel()
```

Anyone knows how to avoid the nasty cast in the end :

```
return MyViewModel(handler) as T
```

Comment: you are doing a dangerous working... the client code expect a `T extends ViewModel` but you give a `MyViewModel`. when the client code use a specific  type of `T` you always got a `ClassCastException`, e.g: `val model:T = factory.create(T::class.java)`

Comment: That's why I would like to know an alternate approach :)

Comment: you can use reflection to instantiate the `ViewModel` or use the 3rd IoC container to create the `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could write:

```
class MyFactory(val handler: Handler) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return modelClass.getConstructor(Handler::class.java).newInstance(handler)
    }
}
```

This will work with any class accepting a `Handler` as constructor argument and will throw `NoSuchMethodException` if the class doesn't have the proper constructor.

Comment: Since this should be called very rarely, the cost of reflection seems reasonable. Would have hoped for some funky Kotlin goodies, but this will do. Thanks!

Comment: Kotlin goodies like reified generic types are unfortunately not available in this case. Because of  type erasure, you can only force cast or use reflection. Also, the default factory already uses reflection to invoke the empty public constructor so the cost would be about the same.